# Auditing child entities while saving parent entity in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a parent child relationship in neo4j and I want to do a save on the parent entity which will implicitly save the child entity
If the entity extends AuditEntity, then I want to set the createTimestamp and updateTimestamp before saving the parent and child entity
To achieve this I was thinking of adding BeforeSaveEvent Application Listner and setting the values there. But this will set the values only for the parent entity. How can I set them on the child entities ?
Or is there any better approach to do this ? 
I am using SDN 4.1.2

```
@Bean
    ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
                if(event.getEntity() instanceof AuditEntity) {
                (AuditEntity) auditEntity = (AuditEntity)event.getEntity();
                auditEntity.setCreateTimeStamp(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
                auditEntity.setUpdateTimeStamp(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
            }

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a relationship from parent to your child entities? Can you not just recursively update them too?